# Make 2 robots collect most weights in grid without overlapping from top left to bottom right

Tags: algorithm

Say you have a grid like this below (it could be any m sized grid). Robots 1 and 2 can only move down or right from S to X. How do you algorithmically make the robots collect the most weights without them ever overlapping? Robots have to move at the same time each time (it has to move and cannot just skip turn/s). I know for them to not overlap they cannot ever have the same y value.

S 1 4 3 3

1 2 4 6 4

2 4 2 1 5

2 1 5 6 1

9 1 2 3 X

I will accept the first answer with the best time & space complexity.

Comment: Can the paths taken by the robots overlap, provided the two robots never share the same y position?

Comment: Also, do the robots have to move simultaneously?

Comment: robots have to move simultaneously and I believe if robots don't share the same y position they won't overlap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem in O(n^3) time | O(n^2) space.

The explanation is that there is going to be max n turns. And you only need to store previous turn to calculate the next turn. In each turn there could be max n^2 combinations of valid positions. Since you have to go through n^2 combinations n times, running time is n^3.

Comment: Please don't delete questions. Note that deleting questions also deletes the answers and everything else that everyone has written.

Answer (score 2):

At every turn, there are at most 4 possible moves:

- robot 1 down, robot 2 down
- robot 1 down, robot 2 right
- robot 1 right, robot 2 down
- robot 1 right, robot 2 right

Here is a recursive solution implemented in Java. For a given position, the best score is the sum of the weights located at that position + the best score amongst the 4 possible moves:

```java
public class Robots
{
    private int[][] grid;
    private int size;

    /*
    * Check if both robots occupy a valid position
    */
    private boolean isValid(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)
    {
        if(x1==size || y1==size || x2==size || y2==size)
            return false;
        if(x1==x2)
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    private int getMax(int s1, int s2, int s3, int s4)
    {
        int max = s1;
        if(s2>max)
            max = s2;
        if(s3>max)
            max = s3;
        if(s4>max)
            max = s4;
        return max;
    }

    /*
    * Computes the best score possible from a starting position
    */
    private int getBestScore(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)
    {
        if(!isValid(x1, y1, x2, y2))
            return 0;
        int s1 = getBestScore(x1+1, y1, x2+1, y2); // robot 1 down, robot 2 down
        int s2 = getBestScore(x1+1, y1, x2, y2+1); // robot 1 down, robot 2 right
        int s3 = getBestScore(x1, y1+1, x2+1, y2); // robot 1 right, robot 2 down
        int s4 = getBestScore(x1, y1+1, x2, y2+1); // robot 1 right, robot 2 right
        return grid[x1][y1] + grid[x2][y2] + getMax(s1, s2, s3, s4);
    }

    public int solve(int[][] grid)
    {
        this.grid = grid;
        size = grid.length;
        return getBestScore(1, 0, 0, 1);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[][] grid = {{0,1,4,3,3}, {1,2,4,6,4}, {2,4,2,1,5}, {2,1,5,6,1}, {9,1,2,3,0}};

        Robots robots = new Robots();
        System.out.println("Best score = " + robots.solve(grid));
    }
}
```

The result for the example given in the question is:

`Best score = 48`

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to solve in O(m^3) time and O(m^2) space, similarly as one robot can be solved in O(m^2) time and O(m) space.

For one robot you have an array for the possible values after k steps (a diagonal line), and then you construct the possible values after k+1 steps by considering the possible two moves.

For two robots it's instead of matrix after k steps with position for one robot on one axis and the the position of the other robot on the other axis - which gives the space requirement, and each matrix element will be based on at most 2x2 from the previous steps and there are O(m) steps to the destination so it should be O(m^3) time.